# convert very large binary string to long

Tags: java, binary, type-conversion, long-integer, logical-operators

I need to covert a large binary string (length = 251) to variable of type Long , to do some Logical operators like ( AND, OR etc.) ,  but an error appear in this operation because of the length of string, as i think !

How could i resolve this problem !?

my Code:

```
System.out.println("value: " + v2.length()); // printing 251
                            Long decimalValue1 = Long.parseLong(v1, 2); //Error here appear.
                          if(type == "AND")
                            {
                                eq = decimalValue1 & decimalValue2;
                            }
                            else if(type == "OR")
                            {
                                eq = decimalValue1 | decimalValue2;   
                            }
```

The error:
For input string: "01000000000000000001000000000010000000010100010001000000100000011101101010010000000001101110001001111101001001000111001000001101101011111000000010000000010010111100010101010011111011011101101111111100"

Comment: A `long` only has place for 64 bits. You can't put such a large binary into a `long`. If you want to do logical operations on an unlimited number of bits, consider using the [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class.

Comment: Presumably a `NumberFormatException`. You should learn to use `e.printStackTrace();` (and then proper logging) instead of printing out `e.getMessage();`. The error messages don't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: Or use a BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by implementing a manual comparison !
it receive 3 parameters , first binary String (val1) and the second one  and the type of operation..

Code:

```
public  String logOperators(String val1,String val2,String type)
{
    String eq="";
    if(val1.length() == val2.length())
    {
        if(type.equals("AND"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < val1.length(); i++) {
                if(val1.charAt(i) == '1' && val2.charAt(i) == '1')
                {
                    eq += "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    eq += "0";
                }
            }
        }
        else if(type.equals("OR"))
        {
            etc..
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Values not equl to each other !");
        return "0";
    }

    return eq;
}
```

simply ..